# VueJS - Can't assign value from mapState to data property after reloading the page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Can't assign the value from mapState to data property after reloading the page, it works if you go to the child page but not if you are already standing in the child page and reloading the browser.

**Computed mapState**

```
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    tsStore: state => state.SchemeStore
  })
}
```

**Data Property**

```
data () {
  return {
    works: '',
    offTime: '',
  }
}
```

**Mounted**

```
if (this.tsStore.singleView) {
  // Set data based on api.
  let single = this.tsStore.singleView
  this.works = single.works
  this.offTime = single.offTime
}
```

After reloading `works` and `offTime` get empty in the data property.

Comment: It seems to work now, iv'e moved the code inside the `mounted` hook to the `updated` hook instead. Can any one confirm that's the right way to go?

Comment: I think `single.works` and `single.offtime` in your Vuex store is loaded after your component has mounted. Yes you can use `updated` hook, or use a watcher. I think you'd rather be better off setting `works` and `offTime` as a separate computed property from `tsStore.singleView.works` and `tsStore.singleView.offTime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem is the `state` being updated after the component was `mounted`;
So, the `updated` method is called instead of `mounted`.
It is visible in this fiddle, where the API call is simulated by the `setTimeout`:

https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/369915/

I think the best way to get the component updated is using `computed properties`, where Vue implements proxies to watch for changes, like this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3mn2xgvr/

I moved the changes to a computed properties so when the state in Vuex changes, all data that depends on that changes.